# Implicit surfaces equations parametrization

Tags: equation, implicit

How to parametrize an implicit surface?  The surface in question is quadratic in terms of x, y, and z.  Ie., 0 = ax squared + bx + cy squared + dy + ez + fz + gxy + hxz + uyz +j.  I want general parametrization for all arbitrary constants from a-j. Answer should probably involve some combination of trigonometric functions of uv.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Comment: OK, could you suggest another forum?  Son suggested this one.

Comment: These are Q&A sites, not forums. There are sites [in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) where this kind of question might be on topic, but please do check their [help] and [tour] for guidance on what's considered acceptable.